# Applying an Expression<> to a LINQ Where clause

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm writing a custom Entity Framework filter. I have a list of IDs, and a user-supplied expression.

```
protected IEnumerable<TColumn> FilterIds;
protected Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TColumn>, bool>> Filter;
```

Now my question is how do I apply the `Filter` expression to a `Where()` clause?

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    if (FilterMode == FilterModeMatchAny && HasFilterIds)
    {
        // Whoops! Can't do this!
        return query.Where(x => Filter(x, FilterIds));
    }
    return query;
```

Comment: a composable filter for LINQ is something like an `Expression<Func<YourRowType, bool>>` - then it would be simply `return query.Where(Filter(...))`. You need to refactor your `Filter` expression to be the thing that LINQ wants. This might mean composing the expression tree  manually. Can we see what `Filter` is currently?

Comment: @MarcGravell: `Filter` is user-supplied. My simplest example looks like `(l, ids) => ids.Contains(l.State)`. I've spent a lot of hours trying to construct the query manually and decided I don't want to go that route.

Comment: OK, but: that's still the wrong signature for LINQ, so it *cannot* work the way you want; there are two permitted signatures, and frankly one of those is hit and miss - the reliable one is `Expression<Func<TSource, bool>>`. So; you're going to *need* to refactor the code to give you one of those. What does the current signature *mean*?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I am filtering rows by whether or not they are contains in my list of `FilterIds`. So the expression takes an instance of the entity and the list of IDs, and it returns a bool. If the expression can't take into account the current list of IDs, it won't do me any good. I know that it is possible. I'm just hoping, and I think, it can be done without constructing the expression manually.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a `Func<IEnumerable<TColumn>, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>` - i.e. "if I give you a list of values, you give me.back a predicate"

Comment: @MarcGravell: More like `Func<T, IEnumerable<TColumn>, Expression<Func<T, bool>>>`. The only thing is I'm building a class so I want to make it as easy on the caller as possible.

Comment: *somebody* is going to have to shape the thing correctly for LINQ. If you don't want that to be your callees, then it is going to have to be you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Combine` method from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23573031/) does pretty much everything you need.  From there you just need to turn the literal value into an expression that computes it (or I guess alter the `Combine` method from that answer so that the intermediate value isn't computed from a lambda but rather is just any expression), and then call the function.

```
protected IEnumerable<TColumn> FilterIds;
protected Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TColumn>> FilterIdsExpression => _ => FilterIds;
protected Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TColumn>, bool>> Filter;

public virtual IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    if (FilterMode == FilterModeMatchAny && HasFilterIds)
    {
        return query.Where(FilterIdsExpression.Combine(Filter));
    }
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but should the first `=>` for `FilterIdsExpression` be `=` instead? Also, `Combine` is not defined for me. Perhaps I'm missing a `using`, although none show up using Ctrl+..

Comment: @JonathanWood the `Combine` extension is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23573031/2322038), you will need the `Replace` extension. Please check the answer I posted, it's using LinqKit.

Comment: @JonathanWood I defined it as a property, not a field.  I did so intentionally, although if you really really want it to be a field instead, that would work.  The link the post links to the source of the Combine method and the code that it uses.

Comment: I seem to have this working (without installing any packages). Still testing...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new expression to invoke the `Filter` using the `FilterIds` and use `Expand` from [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/)

**Edit** Thanks to @Servy's comment. Now I expand only the internal expression instead of entire query.

```
...
protected IEnumerable<TColumn> FilterIds;
protected Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TColumn>, bool>> Filter;

public virtual IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<T> query)
{
    if (FilterMode == FilterModeMatchAny && HasFilterIds)
    {
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = x => Filter.Invoke(x, FilterIds);
        return query.Where(expression.Expand());
    }
    return query;
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting syntax errors. The arguments to `Invoke` give me errors: *Argument 1: cannot convert from 'T' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'*, and *Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TColumn>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'*. Did you mistype something?

Comment: @JonathanWood have you installed the [LinqKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) package?

Comment: No, I haven't. I thought C# could do this stuff. Where are you using something else?

Comment: Use the Package Manager (View->Other Windows->Package Manager Console), then run `Install-Package LinqKit`

Comment: Rather than marking the entire query as expandable, forcing the entirety of it to be searched for things to expand, you can just expand the one expression you create and leave the query as is.